# Getting the value of an object's member through a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object (named resource) used for translating my texts.

```
resource
    .fileNotFound >> "File not found"
    .advSearch >> "Advanced search"
```

Usually I use this like below:

```
alert (resource.advSearch);
```

Now I need to access one of the member of this `resource` object through a variable.

Example:

```
var trans = "advSearch";
```

**My question**: how can I get the translation in my `resource` object for 'advSearch' contained in the trans variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
resource[trans]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[]` notation to access properties as well.

```
resource[trans];
```